# What's the best way to re-index a TDictionary?

Tags: delphi, tdictionary

I have a `TObjectDictionary<Integer, TMyObject>`, and `TMyObject` has an `ID` field that's the key.  The dictionary owns the values.  The keys originally come from a sequence generator, so as deletes and inserts occur, the key values become non-sequential in the dictionary, and I need them to be sequential.  I could pull all the objects into a separate `TList`, renumber their `ID`s, clear the dictionary and re-add the objects with their now-sequential keys, but that seems awfully inelegant.  Is there a better way to do this?

Also, how do I tell a `TObjectDictionary` that it no longer owns its values?

Comment: If the items are to be identified by sequential integer values then surely a dictionary is the wrong collection. Don't you want to hold them in a list or array?

Answer (score 0):

If the key is retrievable from the value then it is probably not the best idea to store that inside a `TDictionary` as then you can't easily rehash all items when their key property changed. That combined with the fact that you can only use `ExtractPair` to keep objects owned by the dictionary alive which is terribly ineffective or hack your way to the private `FOwnerships` field.

As the key/id comes from a sequence generator the insertion order probably happens to be in increasing order which might be the indicator to put the items into a list and keep them ordered by ID. Lookup can then be done with a binary search.

Unless you are fancy and implement your own search tree to satisfy whatever requirements you have.